# Determining the area of a button that was pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I would like to make a button that is able to determine where is is pressed.  So the example is I would like to make a "sheet of paper" button.  The this button would report where on the sheet it was pressed.  What is the best/correct way to do this in Android?

Comment: Try adding a onTouchListener to the view. will give you a point of where the view was touched.

Comment: Like blessenm said - Add an onTouchListener. You can divide the "sheet of paper" into sections based on x and y co-ordinates. Then when the user touches the screen, retrieve the x and y co-ordinates and determine which section it falls under.